# Do other Wizarding schools offer electives not taught at Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Hogwarts has a ton of electives offered after third year, but what about other wizarding schools? Do they offer different electives that aren't offered at Hogwarts?

Any answer from canon sources is much appreciated!

Comment: @Randal'Thor fixed.

Comment: Reopened and upvoted.

Comment: Electives, not sure, but Durmstrang offers a course in The Dark Arts, a subject only taught at Hogwarts for a year.

Comment: https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/The_New_York_Ghost_articles?file=The_New_York_Ghost_-_Ilvermorny.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is briefly mentioned in Goblet Of Fire that Durmstrang has a different attitude to Dark Magic, and one can (could?) actually study Dark Arts there. In Hogwarts, they teach Defence Against Dark Arts only (except the time during the brief Voldemort reign).

Comment: I initially thought that was Malfoy simply bragging, but Hermione does confirm it a bit later on

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an elective though.